# Invalid vector subscript error when accessing i+1

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
Mat draw_ball_location(Mat& img_color, vector<Point> locations) {

    for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {

        if (locations.at(0) == Point(0,0) || locations.at(1) == Point(0,0))
            continue;

        line(img_color, locations.at(i), locations.at(i+1), Scalar(0,255,0),2);
    }

    return img_color;
}
```

I wrote a function that draws the path of the center point of the moving ball using the line function.

I use the line function and the "abort() has been called" message is fired. When debugging, an invalid vector subscript error occurs.

When I searched for this problem, I found that the i+1 index was outside the bounds of the for statement.
So I added the following code.

```
if (i == location.size())
    break;
```

But, it doesn't solve the problem. How do I avoid the invalid vector subscript error?

Answer (score 0):

Vector indexes are zero based, while `.size()` will return the size of the vector. This means the highest index you can access is `.size() - 1`, a single item vector will have a size of 1 but a max index of 0, for example.

The `i < locations.size()` part of the for-loop tells the compiler to run `i++` as long as that condition is true, so to avoid trying to access an index outside the vector, it needs to stop at `i < locations.size() - 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am converting Python code to C++ code. Can you check the original python code?

Comment: @TaeYoon nothing to do with python, as an unrelated language. C++ behavior defined as C++ behaviour. Also `locations.at(0)` is likely should be `locations.at(i)`

Comment: Even if I modify the code, the problem still occurs. A warning message appears indicating that an arithmetic overflow occurs in the line function.Should I use type casting?

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, the invalid vector subscript error likely occurs with

```
locations.at(i+1)
```

which will access one beyond the vector length in the last iteration. [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) says that `vector.at(i)` will throw a out_of_range exception if outside of the vector bounds, but my compiler (gcc) throws a different exception when vector.at(i) is outside the bounds. It is therefore possible that your compiler throws the invalid vector subscript error. I would add a special case to handle what is now the last iteration in your for loop.